# Friedman test with several repetitions

Tags: r, friedman-test

I'd like to run a non parametric test such as the Friedman test on the data of my experiment.

I have several algorithms ($n$) which I'm comparing against each other.
These algorithms are run on $k$ different subjects.
Since the algorithms have a randomized component, I ran each one 30 times on each subject. Therefore, overall I have $n\times k\times30$ data points.

What should I use as input for the Friedman test when having several repetitions? the mean of the repetitions?
I also thought about treating each repetition as a different subject (i.e. $subject_{1,1}, \dots, subject_{1,30}, \dots, subject_{k,1}, \dots, subject_{k,30}$), but I'm not sure it's the right approach.

Or should I use another test altogether?
FWIW, I'm working on R.

Comment: If your only objective is to see if there are differences among algorithms. You could average the 30 results for each subject, as you suggest. Then do a Friedman test on algorithms with subjects as 'random blocks'. You could test $H_0$ that algorithms are the same, but you will get no straightforward information about subject-to-subject variability, and none about within subject variability. Presumably, you are using the nonparamteric Friedman test because you think that the 30 scores for each subject are distinctly nonnormal.

Comment: If scores were nearly normal with equal variances for each subject it would be a 
 traditional two way ANOVA: fixed factor algorithms (n levels), random factor subject (k levels), 30 replications per cell. Then you might learn something about within and among subject variances, information that might be useful in power computations for subsequent similar studies. //  Also, you might get interesting info about algorithm-by-subject interactions--possibly useful insights for design of future algorithms.

Comment: @BruceET thanks for the insight. Yes, as you mention, I cannot assume normality  for the output of my algorithms across subjects. Since averaging the 30 results for each subject might be an option, once the $H_0$ is rejected, is there a way to know _which_ of the algorithms is the one performing better than the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Minitab output for simplified cases with 3 Algorithms, 5 Subjects, and 10 replications.

First, output for the Friedman test on 15 averages of 10.

```
 Friedman Test: AvgScor versus Al blocked by Sub 

 S = 6.40  DF = 2  P = 0.041

                    Sum of
 Al  N  Est Median   Ranks
 1   5      109.33     6.0
 2   5      113.00    10.0
 3   5      116.57    14.0

 Grand median = 112.97
```

There are significant differences among algorithms. It seems fair to say
Algorithm 3 has a higher score than Algorithm 1. Beyond that you could do
2-sample Wilcoxon tests to see if Algorithm 2 is significantly different
from the others, perhaps using a Bonferroni procedure, working at a reduced
significance level to avoid 'false discovery'.

I haven't seen your data, but by the time you average 30 scores, you might
be able to rely on results of a two-way standard ANOVA with 3 Algorithms
and 5 subjects, with one observation (the average) per cell.

```
Analysis of Variance for AvgScor

Source  DF       SS      MS      F      P
Al       2  156.825  78.413  11.62  0.004
Sub      4   11.489   2.872   0.43  0.787
Error    8   53.975   6.747
Total   14  222.289

S = 2.59747   R-Sq = 75.72%   R-Sq(adj) = 57.51%
```

Here you could use an *ad hoc* Tukey HSD procedure to determine which
pairs of Algorithms are different. You also know that the Subject variance
is too small to reject $H_0: \sigma_{Sub}^2 = 0.$ Alternatively, use 
a MLE analysis in R that provides an estimate and CI for $\sigma_{Sub}^2.$

For this demo, I generated fake *normal* data (with SD 5.0), so the full ANOVA
with 10 replications in each cell would be legitimate.

You could try this
with your data, capture the residuals, and look at them in a normal
probability plot to assess how seriously to take findings about interaction
and estimates of within-subject variance $\sigma_e^2.$  Even if information
about variances is imperfect, it might give useful ballpark estimates for power
computations, so you would have some idea whether 30 replications per
subject are necessary.

```
ANOVA: Score versus Alg, Subj 

Factor  Type    Levels  Values
Alg     fixed        3  1, 2, 3
Subj    random       5  1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Analysis of Variance for Score

Source     DF       SS       MS      F      P
Alg         2  2169.29  1084.65  16.70  0.001
Subj        4   256.57    64.14   0.99  0.466
Alg*Subj    8   519.51    64.94   2.39  0.019
Error     135  3662.90    27.13
Total     149  6608.27

S = 5.20890   R-Sq = 44.57%   R-Sq(adj) = 38.82%
```

[image]